# MobileFirst Error: Cannot perform this operation on removed entity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am currently working with an IBM consultant to upgrade our Mobile App from Worklight 5.0.6 to MobileFirst 7. I am deploying locally. I am occasionally getting this error message that prevents me from deploying to the console:

```
[2015-05-28 11:35:16] Deploying application 'MyGPCMobile' with environment 'iphone' to MobileFirst Server... 
[2015-05-28 11:35:18] Failed to deploy application 'MyGPCMobile' to MobileFirst Server: : Cannot perform this operation on removed entity "com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.DifferentialDirectUpdateEntity-com.ibm.worklight.dataaccess.jpa.entity.DifferentialDirectUpdateEntity-117".
```

The consultant suggested I post this here to get an answer as to why this keeps occurring.

I've tried the following things:
If I delete the app from the console and deploy the first time, it seems to work. Subsequent deploys are subjected to generate the error message.

I've also attempted to delete the server and restart Eclipse which seems to be a work around for a while, but then the error returns.

I've also deleted the derby database directory which also seemed to be a workaround momentarily.

I would like to know what is causing this so that it doesn't continue to happen.

Comment: So obviously, it's something to do with differential direct update. :) Now please mentioned: environment OS (Mac/Windows/Linux), if you generate in one OS but deploy in another OS, if you can reproduce this with a clean app or only yours, if this happens on Studio only or on the production server, and if you can supply us with the project or any other end-to-end reproduction steps.

Comment: Idan, I am on a Mac deploying locally. It's only occurred locally within Studio.  I have not tried with a clean app as we've been focused in on the update of this application. I will try a clean app when I get a moment.  This hasn't occurred on a production server.  I could provide the project through a secure channel (IBM's portal if I need to open a service ticket).  However, I'd prefer not to share it on Stackoverflow.  As far as reproducing the steps, I've just done the normal right click on the project and run on Mobilefirst server locally.

Comment: You can upload it to connections and send me an email in notes and I'll take a look.

Comment: Idan, I uploaded the  zip file in Connections. However, it wouldn't let me share with you. Not sure how to proceed so that you have access to the file.

Comment: Send me an email and we'll continue from there... I assume you're an IBMer. If you can't do this, ask from your IBM consultant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: fix available starting iFix release 7.0.0.0-IF201506021502

This has been identified as a defect:
75848: PI42074 EXCEPTION WHEN DEPLOYING IOS ENVIRONMENT CONTAINING A SKIN

Local workaround is as mentioned in the question.
To receive a fix, please open a PMR (support ticket).